# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function select() on null.Magento2

Tags: magento2, database, php-7.2

```
<?php
$connection = $this->getConnection();
$select = $connection->select();
$select = $model->getCollection()
   ->select()
   ->count()
   ->from($this->getDbPrefix() . 'name_table', '*')
   ->where('result', ' likes%');
   return (int)$objectManager->fetchOne($select);
?>
```

I want SELECT COUNT (*) FROM name_table WHERE result LIKE 'likes%' to be executed, and a numeric value is displayed on the page.How do I do it? I'm a beginner. I'll be very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code wrong on two cases.

If `$model`  a model class then  `$model->getCollection()->select()` have to chanages `$model->getCollection()->getSelect()`. athat is  wrong.

Also, `(int)$objectManager->fetchOne($select)` wrong.

You can use collection

> `$model->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('result', ['like' =>
>   'likes%']);`

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array(
    array('like' => '% '.$needle.' %'), //spaces on each side
    array('like' => '% '.$needle), //space before and ends with $needle
    array('like' => $needle.' %') // starts with needle and space after
));
```

Passing the second parameter as an array of arrays will concatenate the conditions using `OR`

I hope it helps!